# mysqli query results to show all rows

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have the following code:

```php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/conn.php'; 

$query = "SELECT title FROM news_event";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

This is fine if there is only one result as I can just echo `$row['title']` but if there are lots of results, how do I get this to loop through and print every row?

I'm sure this is really simple but I'm just not sure what I need to search for in Google.

I'm looking for a `mysqli` equivalent of this:

```php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just replace it with `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_result::fetch_array` :)

```php
while( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
{
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Almost all `mysql_*` functions have a corresponding `mysqli_*` function.

Answer (score 10):

**Simple mysqli solution:**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1');
while ( $rows = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    print_r($rows);//echo "{$row['field']}";
}
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

**With Error Handling:** If there is a fatal error the script will terminate with an error message.

```
// ini_set('display_errors',1); // Uncomment to show errors to the end user.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table WHERE 1');
while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "{$row['field']}";
}
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

**Using iterators:** Support was added with PHP 5.4

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
foreach ( $db->query('SELECT * FROM table') as $row ) {
    print_r($row);//echo "{$row['field']}";
}
$db->close();
```

**Fetch a single record:** This code does not require a loop.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table');
$row = $resource->fetch_assoc();
echo "{$row['field']}";
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

Comment: Please, [do not use try catch for the error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch).

Comment: Hi @YourCommonSense, I agree with you, thanks for the suggestion. As for iterable results, see [example #3 on the PHP documentation for mysqli.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Please do not handle errors manually. Enable error reporting for mysqli instead. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    // Look inside $row here, do what you want with it.
}
```

Look at the associative array examples here (should correspond with fetch_array() versions as well):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop using `foreach`

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM news_event";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
foreach($result as $row) {
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

If you would like to keep the mysqli code and HTML separate, then it's good idea to fetch all into an array and loop later.

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM news_event";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$news_events = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Later in HTML:    

<div>
<?php foreach($news_events as $row): ?>
    <p><?= $row['FirstName'] ?> <?= $row['LastName'] ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```